# How to set UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

when I set `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` to a tableView, still  the separatorview is visble?

I set the property of tableview,

`self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

and in view debug I still found a UITableViewCellSeparatorView in my cell,
How do I remove the separator view?

Comment: Is the separator below all the cells?

Comment: are you set none for Seperator property  from xcode attribute inspector?

Comment: Yes,I set none from Xcode attribute inspector,solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can set UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone in tableview in storyboard.
Here i attach screenshot for more clarification.

[image: How to set UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]

Answer (score 0):

since cells are being reused when presented (with **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier**): you have to use a different identifier for that cell.. I made a custom UITableViewCell subclass for it too.

this is a code where my last cell is a special cell that will load X more cells..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == lastIndex) {
        LoadingNextCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingNextCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[LoadingNextCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LoadingNextCell"];
        }
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading next %d trees..",PRELOAD_TREES];
        return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
     }
     return cell; 
}
```

Customie your cell according to this logic.